# PHPExcel write xlsx file, allowed memory size

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, phpexcel, xls

When I try to generate big file with PHPExcel I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67 bytes)
```

here's example code which causes this:

```
$CI = & get_instance ();
        $CI->load->library ( 'export/PHPExcel' );

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel ();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex ( 0 );

        $rowCount = 1; 
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount,'title'.$rowCount);

    for($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++){ 
        $rowCount++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, "xyz".$rowCount);
    } 


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');  
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 ( $objPHPExcel );
    $objWriter->save ( 'php://output' );
```

Now my question is how to avoid this issue, when I want to generate big xlsx files with PHPExcel? Or maybe you know better lirary for that? I can't change apache/php config to have more memory avaliable. Solution shouldn't depend on memory.

Comment: php can only do so much based on the memory allocation.. The file you are trying to generate is over 128mb (guessing thats your current limit) and as such it cannot do it. Can you not raise your memory limit in php? most (even shared) hosting allows a custom php.ini if you don't have access to the server...

Comment: 128 MB is quite poor limit for a host. Could you alter it through php? `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');`?

Answer (score 0):

By default PHPExcel uses memory for cacheing before you save the result to file or php://output.
You can switch to using php_temp, which is slower, but cheaper in terms of RAM.

Make sure to set settings before creating an instance of PHPExcel:

```
    $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = ['memoryCacheSize' => '128MB'];
    \PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

    $excelObject = new \PHPExcel();
```

Threre are also other values available for cacheMethod, such as MemCache, APC, ISAM, though I haven't tried them. You can see them in the docs of \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory.

Hope it helps. Good luck!